# error: expected primary expression before `>` token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, token

I have this code that has an error and can't find it.

```
    if (Lista.at(i).getStartHour() <= temp->getStartHour() &&
 Lista.at(i).getEndHour() => temp->getEndHour() &&
         Lista.at(i).getStartMinute() < temp->getStartMinute() && 
    Lista.at(i).getEndMinute() > temp->getEndMinute())
```

I get this error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token at that line.
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

`Lista` is a `vector` of objects, same object as `temp`. All functions return `int`. I'm trying to check if those times overlap.

Comment: temp should be a pointer, not an object.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: That wouldn't cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=>` is not a token; it's two tokens, `=` and `>`.

The greater-than-or-equal-to operator is `>=`.